# How to replace Strings in external links of .xls Workbooks?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My goal is to write a CLI tool to mass replace Strings that represent links to external Excel Workbooks. This is done to prepare for a network infrastructure change that will affect host names.

This is only about .xls files - not .xlsx!

I'm using Java and Apache POI, but I'm open to use other libraries, if necessary.

The scenario is that in an ecosystem where Excel is massively used, interconnected Workbooks are spread on different network addresses. This applies only to references in formulas, there are no other data sources like databases.

Example:

```
='\\srvszt03\aevalutation$\HR\[HR 2013.xls]PGM'!F17+'\\srvszt03\aevaluation$\HR\[HR 2013.xls]PGM'!F18
```

The goal would be to replace each occurance of `srvszt03` with `hosthr23` across all sheets of the workbook. After the infrastructure change, Excel users should be able to just continue their work without having to change those references manually.

I tried to implement this using Apache POI 5.2.3 with a rather naive approach:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

            for (Row row : sheet) {

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                        String formula = cell.getCellFormula();

                        if (formula.contains(searchString)) {
                            String newFormula = formula.replace(searchString, replaceString);
                            cell.setCellFormula(newFormula);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This results in a `RuntimeException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No external workbook with name 'test-target.xls'
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.LinkTable.getExternalSheetIndex(LinkTable.java:449)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.getExternalSheetIndex(InternalWorkbook.java:1575)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getSheetExtIx(HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:291)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.get3DReferencePtg(HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:88)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.createAreaRefParseNode(FormulaParser.java:980)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:574)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:325)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1553)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1511)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1872)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1999)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1983)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1940)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.intersectionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1913)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1894)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:2041)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:193)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.HSSFFormulaParser.parse(HSSFFormulaParser.java:79)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellFormulaImpl(HSSFCell.java:530)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellBase.setCellFormula(CellBase.java:124)
    at com.foo.excell.HSSFReplace.replace(HSSFReplace.java:39)
    at com.foo.excell.Change.run(Change.java:77)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2026)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
    at
```

So I assumed that POI verifies the reference in order to make sure the operation doesn't result in a broken file.

I also expected there to be a way to disable the check. So according to an article, I tried to call this upfront:

```
 FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
 evaluator.setIgnoreMissingWorkbooks(true);
```

Which had no effect.

My problem only appears for HSSF(.xls) Workbooks. With XSSF, all works fine by directly manipulating the `ExternalLinksTable`.

So, how can I stop Apache POI from checking for existing external Workbooks or what are alternative approaches to my problem?

Comment: Pretty sure that Excel actually stores the workbook references by ID, and Apache POI de-references that to the name for you (see `LinkTable.getExternalSheetIndex`) - what happens if you try adding the link to the new file to the links table first?

Comment: @Gagravarr I used the debugger to walk through the LinkTable External Block entries. The reference can be found in the encodedURL attribute of the block. So I did the replace operation in the LinkTable prior to changing the cells. This worked, thank you!!
Now, I'll decide wether to access this stuff via reflection or use a local fork of POI.

Comment: What about using [InternalWorkbook.changeExternalReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/model/InternalWorkbook.html#changeExternalReference-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)? That calls [LinkTable.changeExternalReference](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_3/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/model/LinkTable.java?view=markup#l676).

Comment: @AxelRichter I don't know the complete URL (I would have to search for it) upfront. That's why my idea was to replace just the part I know. On the other hand, I struggle to see how to enumerate through all existing ExternalReference URLs. 
It would be a great pleasure to see that I could use POI without the hacky approach.